# Why do my eclipse cdt breakpoints get deleted immediately after they are added?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, breakpoints

This has been working fine for a while, and there are lots of eclipse breakpoint bugs, but this one's not like the others.

I can add a breakpoint, it shows up in the breakpoint list but as soon as I make the breakpoint, the little blue dot with the checkpoint shows up, then the checkpoint goes away.

Here's the gdb trace...

```
355,448 50-break-insert -f xxx
355,448 50^done,bkpt={number="9",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x0000000000435f1e"\
,func="xxx(void const*, unsigned long)",file="xxx.cpp",fullname="xxx.cpp",line="223",thread-groups=["i1"]\
,times="0",original-location="xxx.cpp:223"}
355,448 (gdb)
```

... and then this happens....

```
355,601 51-break-delete 9
355,601 51^done
355,601 (gdb)
```

I'm sure it's some state bug of some config somewhere, and I don't really care why. I have deleted all my breakpoints and restarted,
where is the debugger related cache stuff stored so I can try and delete it?

I'd rather not have to rebuild my workspace.

EDIT:
my gdb version is
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.10-1ubuntu2) 7.10

eclipse version...

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

cdt...

Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools
Version: 8.6.0.201502131403
Build id: @build@

I copied this eclipse setup from a machine 
with this version of gdb and it was working fine.
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1

Comment: Please let us know version of CDT/Eclipse, GDB and platform you are using so we can try and track it down.

Comment: I just noticed. breakpoints that exist before the program starts work fine (stay active). It's only breakpoints that I add after the program has been started in debug mode that get deleted right after they are added.

Answer (score 0):

(There was an earlier answer with some of this information, now deleted?)

With CDT 8.6 there is a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442394) that is now fixed. The gist was there was a race condition that now has [been resolved](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/commit/?id=07dcb970fab42e8af9e3bf87a1014a9bfefbcfc5) in CDT 8.7 (Eclipse Mars).

For the ongoing issue OP raised [bug 19503 against GDB](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19503). Based in part on the information there it seems that potentially turning off debug forked processes may aleviate the situation in Eclipse. In the launch configuration, uncheck the "Automatically debug forked processes", the last of the options marked below:

[image]

Comment: well, it helped a bit. One project works okay, but I get errors when making break points in another project ... Breakpoint installation failed: Given context: (gdb[3].proc[23931].threadGroup[i2],gdb[3].proc[23931].OSthread[0]).thread[0], is already suspended. ,Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-interrupt
Error message from debugger back end:
Invalid thread id: 11 ,Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-interrupt
Error message from debugger back end:
Invalid thread id: 9

Comment: I really want to cry now. So I made a new workspace and started migrating projects in, imported the launch configuration, run it, and I still get the breakpoint errors.

Comment: I am sympathetic, but unfortunately I can't solve your problem. I know the pain you are in as I have been there too. All I can recommend is you ask a new question on SO with the new error message, and/or head to the cdt forum and see if any of the other cdt folk are hanging about there and can help. http://eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.tools.cdt

Comment: Since you need to know something about cdt, maybe you can help me here: I have projects that work and one that doesn't. The broken-ness of the breakpoints followed the project to my new mars install. So the settings causing this problem are somewhere in the project settings. Do you know maybe where in the .project or .cproject file I can look for what might be the problem so I can delete it?

Comment: I think I narrowed it down a bit. I found where it was dying,  I thought it was at startup, but it's not, it's when I call popen, I get this: /build/gdb-HnfxP_/gdb-7.10/gdb/linux-nat.c:1773: internal-error: linux_nat_resume: Assertion `lp != NULL' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,

Comment: What I don't get is why this does not fail at the command line.

Comment: As for stuff in cproject and project file, it seems unlikely anything in there is causing a breakpoint issue directly as they are solely concerned with the building of the program.

Comment: If the problem is in popen, can you make a reduced test case at all that just has popen?

Comment: And a final item for now. GDB 7.10 is very new, much newer than the version of CDT you are using. That is mostly relevant for the user base that is using GDB 7.10. You are at the leading edge, and you may be the first to find such issues :-( If you can work with me to find a reduced test case I can try to fix it, or at least raise a proper bug report.

Comment: for reference, I opened this bug... https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19503  I will try to make a standalone failure test when I have time

Comment: @stu thanks for following this up with the GDB folk. With the extra information you may find turning off debugging forked processes useful? I have amended my answer to include this information.